# How to close modal popup window on click of submit button in angular (without using data-dismiss modal of bootstrap code)?

Tags: angular

How do I close Modal Popup on form submit?

[image]

Comment: What technology are you using to create the modal? Can you share some code?

Comment: @ JeffryHouser bootstrap 4

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ng-bootstrap to create modal, you can declare modalservice in constructor and close function will work.

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbActiveModal){}

    public onClick(id: number): void{
        this.modalService.close();
        //Your code goes here
    }
```

If you are following different logic for modal window. Please post some of you code so that any one give you better solution.

Comment: Please tell how to close bootstrap4 modal ?

Comment: Please refer this site https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

Comment: I referred  but didn't get information for what i was looking for

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/1aeur58f/1/  in this example they have used data-dismiss for closing pop up but on click of save the popup should be closed automatically (using angular but not using Jquery)

Comment: On clicking save button u need to add function like this in html page (click)="function goes here" and in typescript                                     
 public function name(): void{
  this.modalService.close();
 }

Comment: I was following this methodology for modal pop, it was working fine for me.If it was not working means need to see actual code then only. I can able to give any solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165561/discussion-between-rakesh-a-r-and-jay).

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-modal-service-static',
  template: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModal(template)">Create template modal</button>

<ng-template #template>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">Modal</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="modalRef.hide()">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    This is a modal.
  </div>
</ng-template>`
})
export class DemoModalServiceStaticComponent {
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
  }
}
```

use `hide()` method